# esp32 resets when relay switches from ON state to OFF state

Tags: microcontroller, relay, esp8266, solid-state-relay

When I switch a 12v relay from ON to OFF using esp32  then the ESP is restarted. Also it  happens only when there is an AC load. I control 12V relay with a transistor. 
This is my [relay](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjs-Jb1mIjfAhXMeisKHVh0Al8QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fperfectradios.businesstowork.com%2Fleone-l90-csdc-12v-30-amp-t-type-pcb-mountable-relay&psig=AOvVaw0asx0n8BXpKb3mciS_aujx&ust=1544082284655316)

How to solve this

Edit 1-- When I changed the load to a light bulb it works normally fine. But when I switch back to Induction motors the problem persists.

[Circuit link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yvgz.jpg)

Comment: Use scope to see what is going on the ESP power lines when relay toggles.

Comment: @Anonymous yeah but I dont have scope with me. Is there any alternative? I read something about snubber circuit. Will it be the issue?

Comment: some circuit diagram no shed some light. information is not sufficient

Comment: @user19579 added the circuit

Comment: The likely scenario is that there is a bit of feedthrough from the AC being switched and causing the buck converter to come out of regulation.

Comment: @PeterSmith thanks . But how can we solve this?

Comment: Do you have a reverse diode on the relay coil to prevent spikes on disconnection?  If not, that's probably getting all the way back into your supply/ground through the protection diodes.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAZ1W.jpg this is my relay board

Comment: @PeterSmith when I replaced the load with a light bulb instead of motor it works normally

Comment: Look in the UART, the ESP should say why it's restarting when it does. It may be a brownout reset, but it may be something else, so you should check.